# Avoiding allocations and maintaining concurrency when wrapping a callback-based API with an async API on a hot path

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, solace, taskcompletionsource

I have read a number of articles and questions here on StackOverflow about wrapping a callback based API with a `Task` based one using a `TaskCompletionSource`, and I'm trying to use that sort of technique when communicating with a Solace PubSub+ message broker.

My initial observation was that this technique seems to shift responsibility for concurrency. For example, the Solace broker library has a `Send()` method which can possibly block, and then we get a callback after the network communication is complete to indicate "real" success or failure. So this `Send()` method can be called very quickly, and the vendor library limits concurrency internally.

When you put a Task around that it seems you either serialize the operations ( `foreach message await SendWrapperAsync(message)` ), or take over responsibility for concurrency yourself by deciding how many tasks to start (eg, using TPL dataflow).

In any case, I decided to wrap the `Send` call with a guarantor that will retry forever until the callback indicates success, as well as take responsibility for concurrency. This is a "guaranteed" messaging system. Failure is not an option. This requires that the guarantor can apply backpressure, but that's not really in the scope of this question. I have a couple of comments about it in my example code below.

What it does mean is that my hot path, which wraps the send + callback, is "extra hot" because of the retry logic. And so there's a lot of `TaskCompletionSource` creation here.

The vendor's own documentation makes recommendations about reusing their `Message` objects where possible rather then recreating them for every `Send`. I have decided to use a `Channel` as a ring buffer for this. But that made me wonder - is there some alternative to the `TaskCompletionSource` approach - maybe some other object that can also be cached in the ring buffer and reused, achieving the same outcome?

I realise this is probably an overzealous attempt at micro-optimisation, and to be honest I am exploring several aspects of C# which are above my pay grade (I'm a SQL guy, really), so I could be missing something obvious. If the answer is "you don't actually need this optimisation", that's not going to put my mind at ease. If the answer is "that's really the only sensible way", my curiosity would be satisfied.

Here is a fully functioning console application which simulates the behaviour of the Solace library in the `MockBroker` object, and my attempt to wrap it. My hot path is the `SendOneAsync` method in the `Guarantor` class. The code is probably a bit too long for SO, but it is as minimal a demo I could create that captures all of the important elements.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal class Message { public bool sent; public int payload; public object correlator; }

// simulate third party library behaviour
internal class MockBroker
{
    public bool TrySend(Message m, Action<Message> callback)
    {
        if (r.NextDouble() < 0.5) return false; // simulate chance of immediate failure / "would block" response
        Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(100); m.sent = r.NextDouble() < 0.5; callback(m); }); // simulate network call
        return true;
    }

    private Random r = new();
}

// Turns MockBroker into a "guaranteed" sender with an async concurrency limit
internal class Guarantor
{
    public Guarantor(int maxConcurrency)
    {
        _broker = new MockBroker();
        // avoid message allocations in SendOneAsync
        _ringBuffer = Channel.CreateBounded<Message>(maxConcurrency);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxConcurrency; i++) _ringBuffer.Writer.TryWrite(new Message());
    }

    // real code pushing into a T.T.T.DataFlow block with bounded capacity and parallelism
    // execution options both equal to maxConcurrency here, providing concurrency and backpressure
    public async Task Post(int payload) => await SendOneAsync(payload);

    private async Task SendOneAsync(int payload)
    {
        Message msg = await _ringBuffer.Reader.ReadAsync();
        msg.payload = payload;
        // send must eventually succeed
        while (true)
        {
            // *** can this allocation be avoided? ***
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
            msg.correlator = tcs;
            // class method in real code, inlined here to make the logic more apparent
            Action<Message> callback = (msg) => (msg.correlator as TaskCompletionSource<bool>).SetResult(msg.sent);
            if (_broker.TrySend(msg, callback) && await tcs.Task) break;
            else
            {
                // simple demo retry logic
                Console.WriteLine($"retrying {msg.payload}");
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
        }
        // real code raising an event here to indicate successful delivery
        await _ringBuffer.Writer.WriteAsync(msg);
        Console.WriteLine(payload);
    }

    private Channel<Message> _ringBuffer;
    private MockBroker _broker;
}

internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // at most 10 concurrent sends
        Guarantor g = new(10);
        // hacky simulation since in this demo there's nothing generating continuous events,
        // no DataFlowBlock providing concurrency (it will be limited by the Channel instead),
        // and nobody to notify when messages are successfully sent
        List<Task> sends = new(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) sends.Add(g.Post(i));
        await Task.WhenAll(sends);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid the allocation of `TaskCompletionSource` instances, by using lightweight [`ValueTask`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/)s instead of `Task`s. At first you need a reusable object that can implement the [`IValueTaskSource<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.ivaluetasksource-1) interface, and the `Message` seems like the perfect candidate. For implementing this interface you can use the [`ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.manualresetvaluetasksourcecore-1) struct. This is a mutable struct, so **it should not be declared as `readonly`**. You just need to delegate the interface methods to the corresponding methods of this struct with the very long name:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks.Sources;

internal class Message : IValueTaskSource<bool>
{
    public bool sent; public int payload; public object correlator;

    private ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<bool> _source; // Mutable struct, not readonly

    public void Reset() => _source.Reset();
    public short Version => _source.Version;
    public void SetResult(bool result) => _source.SetResult(result);

    ValueTaskSourceStatus IValueTaskSource<bool>.GetStatus(short token)
        => _source.GetStatus(token);
    void IValueTaskSource<bool>.OnCompleted(Action<object> continuation,
        object state, short token, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags flags)
            => _source.OnCompleted(continuation, state, token, flags);
    bool IValueTaskSource<bool>.GetResult(short token) => _source.GetResult(token);
}
```

The three members `GetStatus`, `OnCompleted` and `GetResult` are required for implementing the interface. The other three members (`Reset`, `Version` and `SetResult`) will be used for creating and controlling the `ValueTask<bool>`s.

Now lets wrap the `TrySend` method of the `MockBroker` class in an asynchronous method `TrySendAsync`, that returns a `ValueTask<bool>`

```
static class MockBrokerExtensions
{
    public static ValueTask<bool> TrySendAsync(this MockBroker source, Message message)
    {
        message.Reset();
        bool result = source.TrySend(message, m => m.SetResult(m.sent));
        if (!result) message.SetResult(false);
        return new ValueTask<bool>(message, message.Version);
    }
}
```

The `message.Reset();` resets the `IValueTaskSource<bool>`, and declares that the previous asynchronous operation has completed. A `IValueTaskSource<T>` supports only one asynchronous operation at a time, the produced [`ValueTask<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1) can be awaited only once, and it can no longer be awaited after the next `Reset()`. That's the price you have to pay for avoiding the allocation of an object: you must follow stricter rules. If you try to bend the rules (intentionally or unintentionally), the `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>` will start throwing `InvalidOperationException`s all over the place.

Now lets use the `TrySendAsync` extension method:

```
while (true)
{
    if (await _broker.TrySendAsync(msg)) break;

    // simple demo retry logic
    Console.WriteLine($"retrying {msg.payload}");
    await Task.Delay(500);
}
```

You can print in the `Console` the `GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true)` before and after the whole operation, to see the difference. Make sure to run the application in Release mode, to see the real picture. You might see that the difference in not that impressive, because the size of a `TaskCompletionSource` instance is pretty small compared to the bytes allocated by the `Task.Delay`, and by all the `string`s generated for writing stuff in the `Console`.

Comment: Killing it, Mr Zoulias. I went looking for more information about this `ManualResetValueTaskCore`  and read through Stephen Toub's [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27558), which gave me some additional footing, although the details are certainly too much for me. If Stephen Toub says implmenting something is "challenging", I'm going to take the one they've built for me, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @allmhuran you can tell from the name of the `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>` struct, that it was not intended for everyday use. 